# Multiple monitor with virtual gap between them

Tags: multi-monitor, display, monitors, display-settings

I'm having a problem with my system for some time. I've been hitting this problem for some time. I looked for people with a problem similar to mine  but found none. I use 3 monitors in portrait mode 24" each(1920x1080;1920x1200;1920x1080).

```
What I want                     What I have 
+------++--------++------+    +------+  +--------+  +------+
|      ||        ||      |    |      |  |        |  |      |
|      ||        ||      |    |      |  |        |  |      | 
|  1   ||    2   ||  3   |    |  1   |  |    2   |  |   3  | 
|      ||        ||      |    |      |  |        |  |      | 
|      ||        ||      |    |      |  |        |  |      |  
+------++--------++------+    +------+  +--------+  +------+
```

I keep on getting a weird virtual gap between them and I can lose icons and opened window apps there. I have a GTX1080Ti for GPU and  `My DE: MATE 1.18.2.`. I want to have the gap gone like the monitors are really close to each other, I would like the reverse action of this post [Stretch window over two monitors with "gap" in between](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182182/stretch-window-over-two-monitors-with-gap-in-between) . I think something might be done with `xrandr` here but I just can't figure it out, here is my config:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4920 x 1920, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1200x1920+1920+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected 1080x1920+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-1 connected 1080x1920+3840+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 368mm x 207mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1920` is the width in landscape mode, so becomes the height in portrait mode.  Your config starts each monitor 1920 pixels from the start of the last monitor, so there's a 700-900 pixel gap between them:

```
+0        +1920       +3840
+------+  +--------+  +------+    total: 4920w x 1920h
|      |  |        |  |      |
|1080w |  |1200w   |  |1080w | 
|  1   |  |    2   |  |   3  | 
|      |  |        |  |      |  
+------+  +--------+  +------+ 
       |  |        |  |
        840  gaps   720
```

The overall geometry is in the `xrandr` output.  Notice the starting X positions are multiples of 1920 -- you'd expect that in landscape mode, but not in portrait where the widths are smaller:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4920 x 1920    [<== total]
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1200x1920+1920+0 left [<== WidthxHeight+StartX+StartY]
   ...
HDMI-0 connected 1080x1920+0+0 left        [<== WidthxHeight+StartX+StartY]
   ...
HDMI-1 connected 1080x1920+3840+0 right    [<== WidthxHeight+StartX+StartY]
   ...
```

---

What you want:

```
+0      +1080     +2280
+------++--------++------+   total: 3360w x 1920h
|      ||        ||      |
|1080w ||1200w   ||1080w | 
|  1   ||    2   ||   3  | 
|      ||        ||      |  
+------++--------++------+
```

You don't provide an exact xrandr command that you use to achieve what you have, but I think this will get what you want (I'm not certain about the rotations; they're from your `xrandr` output):

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0  --rotate left   --pos 0x0          \
       --output DVI-D-0 --rotate left   --right-of HDMI-0  \
       --output HDMI-1  --rotate right  --right-of DVI-D-0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly!! <3 Thanks for the help !!!

Comment: Nice. I also had a gap after rotating a monitor. xrandr is works surprisingly well these days